# Trigger para proibir inserção de escala que já está atuando naquela data SQL Server

Tags: sql, select, sql-update, trigger, sql-insert

**Obrigado pelo seu tempo!**

1° Vou colocar os dados e depois irei apontar a minha dúvida, já tentei mil vezes e não consigo chegar a lógica que dê certo.

Tenho a seguinte tabela

- Tabela Escala

```
CREATE TABLE ESCALA 
(   
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    STS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    TIPO VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    PESSOA_ID_CREATE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PESSOA_ID_UPDATE INTEGER,
    DATACRIACAO DATETIME NOT NULL,
    DATAMOD DATETIME 

    CONSTRAINT PK_ESCALA_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PESSOA_ESCALA_ID_CREATE FOREIGN KEY (PESSOA_ID_CREATE)    
        REFERENCES PESSOA(ID)  
)
```

> Meu objetivo é o seguinte:

Quando eu inserir ou atualizar uma escala, é necessário verificar se:

1. A data ou hora da escala inserida ou atualizada já esta sendo usada
2. Segue ilustração de exceções que devem ser atendidas pela Trigger:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após vários testes e tentativas cheguei a Triggers(Insert e Update separadas):

- INSERT

```
USE [RowDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_INSERT]    Script Date: 24/05/2019 08:27:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_INSERT] ON [dbo].[ESCALA]
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS

BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED I 
                            INNER JOIN DBO.ESCALA E
                       ON   I.TIPO = E.TIPO AND E.STS = 'ATIVO'

                            WHERE   



                                    CONVERT(date, I.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) AND CONVERT(date, E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)
                                    OR 
                                    CONVERT(date, I.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)   BETWEEN CONVERT(date, E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) AND CONVERT(date, E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)

                                    AND 

                                    CONVERT(time, I.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) BETWEEN CONVERT(time, E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) AND CONVERT(time, E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)

                                    OR
                                    CONVERT(time, I.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)   BETWEEN CONVERT(time, E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) AND CONVERT(time, E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)

              )
    BEGIN   

        RAISERROR ('NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL ATUALIZAR A ESCALA, NÃO É POSSÍVEL DUAS ESCALAS DO MESMO TIPO ATUAREM NA MESMA DATA/HORA',16,1);

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO ESCALA(NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL, PESSOA_ID_CREATE, DATACRIACAO)
            SELECT NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL, PESSOA_ID_CREATE, DATACRIACAO FROM INSERTED
    END     
END
```

- UPDATE

```
USE [RowDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_UPDATE]    Script Date: 24/05/2019 08:27:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_UPDATE] ON [dbo].[ESCALA] 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED I 
                            INNER JOIN DBO.ESCALA E
                       ON   I.TIPO = E.TIPO AND E.STS = 'ATIVO' AND E.ID != I.ID

                            WHERE   

                                    CONVERT(date, I.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) AND CONVERT(date, E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)
                                    AND 
                                    CONVERT(time, I.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) BETWEEN CONVERT(time, E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) AND CONVERT(time, E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)

                                    OR

                                    CONVERT(date, I.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)   BETWEEN CONVERT(date, E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) AND CONVERT(date, E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)
                                    AND
                                    CONVERT(time, I.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)   BETWEEN CONVERT(time, E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) AND CONVERT(time, E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)


              )
    BEGIN   

        RAISERROR ('NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL ATUALIZAR A ESCALA, NÃO É POSSÍVEL DUAS ESCALAS DO MESMO TIPO ATUAREM NA MESMA DATA/HORA',16,1);

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
            UPDATE E
               SET E.NOME                 = I.NOME
                 , E.STS                  = I.STS
                 , E.TIPO                 = I.TIPO
                 , E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL = I.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL
                 , E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   = I.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL
                 , E.PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     = I.PESSOA_ID_UPDATE
                 , E.DATAMOD              = GETDATE()



              FROM INSERTED I
             INNER JOIN ESCALA E
                ON E.ID = I.ID
    END

END
```

Espero que eu tenha conseguido explicar o meu problema, qualquer dúvida só postar.
Se não souber como fazer vote para ranquear a pergunta, preciso muito de uma solução.
Com as triggers que criei as vezes ainda sim, impede o cadastro quando não deveria, ou deixa cadastrar quando não pode.
Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Verifique se seu SGBD implementa o operador OVERLAPS para campos timestamp.

Comment: Faltou dizer qual o SGBD que você está usando... uma trigger no Oracle (PL-SQL) vai ser diferente de uma trigger no mysql por exemplo...

Comment: precisa mesmo de uma *trigger*? não poderia fazer isso com uma *procedure*?

Comment: @wensiso pelo `RAISERROR` posso dizer que é `sql-server` mas seria interessente o Gustavo colocar essa tag na pergunta para facilitar

Comment: Coloquei a TAG galera, acho que não apareceu ai :(

Comment: Ricardo, pode ser também, funcionando :D